# SQLCODE=-501, SQLSTATE=24501 with Cursor

Tags: db2

I have written one procedure. I am getting the below error.
Can someone help me with this.

```
Create procedure p1()

declare cur1 cursor WITH HOLD for STMT1;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '24501' 
BEGIN
OPEN index_list ;
set exitcode = 1;

END ;  

set TEXT =();
PREPARE STMT1 FROM TEXT;     

OPEN cur1 ;

 FETCH FROM cur1 INTO VAR2,
                            VAR1 ;

 WHILE (SQLCODE = 0)
       DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SET PASSTHRU SAMPLE' ;
        ----
        -----
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SET PASSTHRU RESET' ;       

FETCH FROM cur1 INTO VAR2,
                            VAR1 ; 

END WHILE;
```

This is my code outline. My problem is After that 'SET PASSTHRU RESET', cursor is getting closed &  the second fetch  is failing with the below error.even I specified the curos a WITH HOLD option.

error:
The cursor specified in a FETCH statement or CLOSE statement is not open or a cursor variable in a cursor scalar function reference is not open.. SQLCODE=-501, SQLSTATE=24501, DRIVER=4.17.30
Run of routine failed.

can some one please let me know, what i have to add here.
I am new bee for db2  & never met with this scenario. That is why I am asking the experts.

Comment: There's a number of problems here 1) If you're preparing the statement you end up using in a cursor, you call `PREPARE` _before_ `DECLARE CURSOR` (you can just declare the cursor, though).  2) You declare the cursor as `cur1`, but fetch from `index_list`, so the message you're getting really isn't surprising.  3) The statement might still succeed, [but pass something _other_ than `SQLCODE = 0`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_p.dita)....

Comment: ... 4) The use of a cursor means you're going to RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) this.  You really want to do this in blocks, or the entire thing in one batch.  Supposedly DB2 has utilities to talk between boxes (as in, actually query tables in different servers, or even different RDBMSs as one), but I've never set them up.

Comment: Sorry Guys I have edited this outline, as this is not my original code.But I found solution I handled this as an exception & i declared exit code = 1 inside that exception & it is working now.I can able to run through my records. Thanks for your support.Added to the question